# golang gorp select with nullString fail

Tags: select, go, nullable, gorp

I define order struct like t

```
type Order struct {
    Id      nullString `db:"O_ID"`
    CusTel  int64      `db:"O_CUS_TEL"`
}
```

And I installed a Order object as order, when I called: `dbmap.SelectInt("SELECT count(*) FROM ORDERS WHERE O_ID=?",o.Id)`
i got such error:

```
[gorp] SELECT count(*) FROM ORDERS WHERE O_ID=? []
Search order by id:{{00000001 true}} fail:Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

But if i use it like that:

```
dbmap.Db.Exec("SELECT count(*) FROM ORDERS WHERE O_ID=?",o.Id)
```

It`s done.

I don`t know why?

Comment: What type is your `nullString`? Does it work with `sql.NullString`?

Comment: the nullString definition:
type NullString struct {
 sql.NullString
}

Comment: Your `nullString` type isn't implicitly equivalent to `sql.NullString`: http://play.golang.org/p/r57VRNDxrw - either type cast it or (better) just use `sql.NullString`, which makes it clearer for others.

Comment: I use NullString, because I need this this struct can be transfer to Json. I define it like that:
`type NullString struct {
 sql.NullString
}

func (s *NullString) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
 s.String = strings.Trim(string(data), `"`)
 //fmt.Printf("JsonValue:%v",string(data))
 //s.String = string(data)
 s.Valid = true
 return nil
}

func (s NullString) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(s.String)
}`